# Angular Polyfills and other 6 index.html files path error

Tags: angular

I am deploying angular build at IIS my main problem i think is that of base

This is my path where Angular build is hosted at IIS Manager

**Where First ClientApp is my Application at IIS**

`E:\IIS Projects\ElasticCoreWebAPI_Public\feature\ClientApp\ClientApp\`  here is my built

this is my index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>KEENU CFRS</title>
  <base href="/ClientApp">
  <!--// "build": "ng build --base-href=/CFRS.WebUI/",-->

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="mat-typography">
  <app-root>
      <div class="main-spinner-wrapper">
        <div class="donut"></div>
      </div>
  </app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
```

This is my build publish command

`ng build --prod --base-href /ClientApp/`

This is where built is going

```
  "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
```

i am getting my built at dist

this is my built output picture
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by giving the Server Address where the build is deployed if the build is deployed in Root Folder then in index.html

```
<base href="/">
```

If website is somewhere deployed inside the physical folder of the Application then from Url when application is browser copy the Url except root folder then that is your WebsiteAddress

```
<base href="/WebSiteAddress">
```

Command for making production build if build is deployed in root folder

```
ng build --prod
```

If website is somewhere deployed inside the physical folder of the Application then

```
ng build --prod --base-href /WebSiteAddress/
```